# PHP and Apache error to inport files from another folder

Tags: php, windows, apache

Dears I´m having strange error on import files in PHP  from another folders, I tryied `dirname(__DIR__)`  and gives   'Uncaught Error: not found in D:/project/'.

Than I tryied with define('LIB','D:\project'), and it continues giving error on use.

What to do

my project have this tree:

[project folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdWPy.png)

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sIAd.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give code as text instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

You sould try this

Use **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**

**$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** will point to the main folder.

*for example if the file is in **project/fol/file.php** project is the main folder, you can do it like this **$root.'fol/file.php'***

***Example You dir***

```
root/folder1/file.php <----- This file
 |  /folder2/folder3/file.php <----- Second file
 |  /folder4/folder/folder/YouHere.php <----- You include other part here !
```

***In PHP file***

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
require_once($root.'folder1/file.php');
require_once($root.'folder2/folder3/file.php');
```

Comment: It continues with same error I will move from windows to linux and try.

Comment: can i see you script ?

Comment: In the file in root of dir

Comment: `require_once('env.php');
require_once('request/Request.php');
require_once('response/Response.php');
require_once('middleware/Factory.php');
require_once('oauth/OAuth.php')`

Comment: `require_once 'D:\envel\env.php';
require_once LIB.'\oauth\OAuth.php';
require_once LIB.'\error\LoginErrorHandler.php'; `   this imports is in app folder   /project_name/app/login_api.php

Comment: try this $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
 require_once($root.'envel\env.php');

Comment: $root will be project_name/

Comment: if file in root dir you just do require_once($root.'filename.php');

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it, the issue is in xampp configuration file, it had a grant Access Subfolders: FALSE

I  reinstall it.